# git checkout to particular folder

Tags: git

I am newbie to git, I want to get update from remote to local only in particular folder of the local branch for that i did the below:

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/branch-name -- /path/to/particular/folder
```

I got the latest code to that particular folder but when I perform `git status` it shows the file which got latest as modified file (as staged file), but I don't want this.

My requirement is when I perform `git status`, it has to show message like `everything is up-to-date`.

Do I need to change above mentioned `git fetch` and `git checkout` commands or any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

When you `checkout` only particular file or folder, it changes your working directory. So obviously those files are in `modified` status.

If you want everything to be `up-to-date`  - You need to commit those files to your local branch.

You should ask yourself - why do you checkout only particular file or folder? This is not a common workflow. You may do it in some specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you're working with GIT in the wrong way because - not like in other source-control systems - a file or folder is not something that stand for itself.
You probably want to take changes that were made on one commit (probably on a different branch) into your local branch.
If that is the case then the best action is to perform a [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) of a certain commit.

Answer (score 1):

Git is not SVN. You don't checkout a revision into a certain folder. You have **one** working copy. In that working copy you can

```
git checkout branchname
```

in order to check out a single branch in this working copy. If you want to simultaneously check out two different branches of the same repo, you need two working copies.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with lgal S said also you can `git stash` your code and then `pull` your update code and then apply change after you finish it 
the good about `git stash` is you don't have to commit your change if not finish yet you just keep it and `pull` your updates then back to your work and after finish it your can `commit` it you can look on documention of `git stash` [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)